# Reference a workflow activity from a different project within the same solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint, assemblies, workflow-foundation

How can I reference workflow activities from a different SharePoint project within the same solution?

What I've tried:

I created a new SharePoint 2013 project and called it "ReferencingTest". Then I added a workflow to it.

Then, I created a different SharePoint 2013 project within the same solution and called it "FrameworkTest". I added a new Workflow Activity to it called "FrameworkActivity".

Now I want to use the "FrameworkActivity" within the "ReferencingTest" project. As you can see below, it's added to the references. It's visible in the toolbox. But when trying to drop the activity to the workflow, the mouse icon changes to show that this is not permitted.

As you can see below, "ReferencingTest" has a reference to the "FrameworkTest" project. I've tried adding the FrameworkActivity to the referencingTest project, and even tried adding the reference in the XAML for the ReferencingTest workflow. Any other ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding FrameworkActivity assemly to GAC.

Take the assembly from bin\Debug\PartitionedWorkflowBuild\FrameworkActivity.dll

Not from bin\Debug Folder.

Also check: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73c4e1bf-e54b-4d6a-b0d3-896bbba96c83/tfs-2010-custom-workflow-activity-cannot-add-activity-to-workflow?forum=tfsbuild

Comment: I'll try that, but it's a declarative activity not a code activity. Don't think declarative ones are kept in GAC?

Comment: How did you add that declarative activity?

Comment: Right click SharePoint project -> add -> Workflow Custom Activity. These are composed of just XAML.

Comment: No. Here's the project, try it: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3FfvILnofhRb204clR2V3pzTEk

Comment: Check the updated answer. Its working for me. Take the assembly from bin\Debug\PartitionedWorkflowBuild not from bin\Debug

Comment: It worked! I was adding the wrong assembly to GAC. Where did you learn about PartitionedWorkflowBuild? Haha! https://www.google.com.mt/search?q=PartitionedWorkflowBuild

Comment: If you go to tools, then Choose toolbox items -> you will see your activity is referenced from there only.